# Can true unit tests always be run in parallel?

Tags: unit-testing, go, tdd

### Background:

I'm writing a lot of go code, using the `go test` tool and the provided `"testing"` package for, well, testing. Most of the testing that I do is unit testing, within the TDD discipline. These "units" under test are never permitted to depend on stateful externalities like persistent storage, a network hop, etc., but receive fake, in-memory implementations of those externalities usually in "constructor/builder" functions (yes, I know they aren't constructors in the traditional sense).

### The Problem:

It has long bothered me that the `go test` tool always runs test functions in the same deterministic order. This has, in a few cases, allowed race conditions to hide in the code. One way to find these bugs is by setting the `-race` flag. Another might be to always run unit tests in parallel...

### The Question:

Is there *ever* a situation in which *isolated* unit tests could not or should not *always* be run in parallel (using the `-parallel` flag)?

Comment: Unit tests *should* be deterministic, which is why the `-parallel` is an option you can use when needed explicitly. If a unit test is going to fail, it should fail every single time. You should definitely test for incorrect behavior when running parts of your code in parallel or in any order, just like you would any other error condition, but that doesn't belong in most people definition of unit tests.

Comment: I agree, and I'm hoping that I'm not overlooking any obvious conflicting cases.

Comment: Obvious conflicting cases of what exactly? You either write unit tests that can run in parallel, or you don't. It's completely up to you if you want to run your tests in parallel, but most people don't want that as a default, because unit tests should execute exactly the same every time.

Answer (score 1):

The `parallel` flag is actually a way to test the tests themselves (besides speeding them up). Finding a test breaks randomly when run in non deterministic order indicates a bad test as often as it does bad code.

Ruby's test runners do something interesting (both Rspec and Minitest) - they randomize the test order on each run, but print an integer seed that was used for the run. This allows the error to be reproduced while still making sure that no tests depend on implicit ordering. I don't know of any Go test runner doing this, but that would be quite useful.

Comment: Ginkgo allows randomization. GoConvey almost had this feature too.

Comment: Randomized execution is still different than parallel execution.